# How do I solve this to change values to keys instead?

Tags: dictionary, key, key-value

I would like to change the values to keys and keys to values.

Here is what I have tried:

```
def groups_per_user(group_dictionary):
    user_groups = {}
    # Go through group_dictionary
    for key, value in group_dictionary.items():
        # Now go through the users in the group
        for user in value:
            if user in user_groups:
                user_groups[user].append(key)
            user_groups[user] = key
            # Now add the group to the the list of
# groups for this user, creating the entry
# in the dictionary if necessary

    return(user_groups)

print(groups_per_user({"local": ["admin", "userA"],
        "public":  ["admin", "userB"],
        "administrator": ["admin"] }))
```

And this is the error i get:

```
Error on line 18:
    "administrator": ["admin"] }))
Error on line 8:
    user_groups[user].append(key)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'
```

However, i realised that when i change the line
`user_groups[user] = key`
to
`user_groups[user] = [key]`

it works, and it has nothing to do with the AttributeError

Any explanation on this would be greatly appreciated!